# Get each price per month for a category?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I have data with the entities `date, name, price`. I managed to get distinct categories in the `Categories` colume for each name with `= LEFT(B2;FIND(" ";B2))`. In fact I want to get for each categorie the summed up monthly prices per month.

My sheet:
[image: My Data:]

I tried:

`=SUMIF(B2:B6;LEFT(B2;FIND(" ";B2));C2:C6)`

However, this formula returns `0` and also does not give me the prices per categorie and per month.

I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: do you want to use `col E` or do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: @Raystafarian Thx for your answer! I want to use colume `E` and next to colume `E` I want to have the summed up price for each categorie per month.

Comment: You didn't specify if you're using excel or google spreadsheets. If excel, what version?

Comment: @Raystafarian Right now I am using `excel 2010`. However, I am willing to switch to google if it works much easier there...

Comment: I'd recommend looking at VBA - `for each` loop for unique and `month()` function. Try to come up with a possible solution and you'll get help where you're stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a sum on each row which will sum for the category of the current row and the month of the current row you can use `SUMIFS` like this

`=SUMIFS(C:C;E:E;E2;A:A;">"&EOMONTH(A2;-1);A:A;"<="&EOMONTH(A2;0))`

`SUMIFS` requires Excel 2007 or later

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMIF(E:E,E2,C:C)` will sum the categories for you

I think if you want to sum categories by date, you might want to use a Pivot Table or write a Macro

You can write a `=sumif` function with multiple `criteria` but I'm not sure how you would define the "date rage" for each new criteria